# Project dependency on the assembled jar

Tags: maven-2, dependencies

There are two Maven managed projects. The first project utilises the maven-assembly-plugin as part of the package phase, which results in the `first-project-<version>-distribution.jar` file. This file gets installed/deployed together with the `first-project-<version>.jar` (i.e. no distribution suffix).

The second project needs to have a runtime dependency on the assembled jar (i.e. `first-project-<version>-distribution.jar`) in order for that file to be copied together with other dependencies into one folder as part of the `dependency:copy-dependencies` action. Specifying the version of the dependency with `-distribution` at the end does not work.

How can this be achieved? Is there any other way to pull file `first-project-<version>-distribution.jar` from the artifact repository as part of the `dependency:copy-dependencies` action executed for the depended (second) project?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snippet from the Maven-Assembly documentation:

> Sets the id of this assembly. This is a symbolic name for a particular
>   assembly of files from this project. Also, aside from being used to
>   distinctly name the assembled package by attaching its value to the
>   generated archive, the id is used as your artifact's classifier when
>   deploying.

This means in other words that you have to give the classifier "distribution" for your dependency.